# Add 1 Line with counter and change first with last Header using fputcsv in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fputcsv

I wrote a little script which will take a CSV from a URL ...Add a Row and import it into mysql database...

All works fine but one thing

how can I change the content of Headline

I use this to write my content into a New File

```
$counter = 0;               
$data[53] = $counter++;

           fputcsv($handle2,$data,$delimiter = ";", $enclosure = '"');
```

This will add a row with a counter after the last line of my CSV file (My CSV has no unique ID so I have to add one before I can import the CSV for my needs)

It works fine but I have to change some things via shell in CSV File directly but id should be done directly in Script

The New added Line begins in first Headline with 0 but it should begin with something like uniqueid or another name and not with the counter value...but I don't know how I should do that.

```
instead of

0
1
2
3++

I need something heading like

uniqueid
1
2
3++
```

Also I want to change the Heading of $data[1] with the heading of $data[53]

```
///////////UPDATE////////
    if($loadfile == true){
    if (($handle1 = fopen("http://someurl.com/csv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        if (($handle2 = fopen("test.csv", "w")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle1, 99999, ";", $enclosure = '"')) !== FALSE) {
               $data[] = $counter++;
               fputcsv($handle2,$data,$delimiter = ";", $enclosure = '"');

            }
            fclose($handle2);
        }
        fclose($handle1);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Succes ;)")</script>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not make much sense to me. Data that is put into cvs file depends on what you have in $data variable. So are you asking how to modify $data?

Comment: And second question - what is desired data type "uniqueid"?

Comment: Yes i want to modify $data to get a Heading with the Name "uniqueid" and the value in end of each line should be the counter value.....idont know exactly what you mean with data type but my uniqeid content is numeric.....uniqueid VARCHAR(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's fairly simple

```
if ($loadfile == true) {
    if (($handle1 = fopen("http://someurl.com/csv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        if (($handle2 = fopen("test.csv", "w")) !== FALSE) {
            $counter = 0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle1, 99999, ";", $enclosure = '"')) !== FALSE) {

                // if you want to have the id at the last column
                $data[] = ($counter == 0) ? "uniqueid" : $counter;

                // or alternatively for the id at the first column
                //($counter == 0) ? array_unshift($data, "uniqueid") : array_unshift($data, $counter);

                fputcsv($handle2,$data,$delimiter = ";", $enclosure = '"');
                $counter++;
            }
            fclose($handle2);
        }
        fclose($handle1);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Succes ;)")</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Thank You that looks nice...I will test It...Thank you for taking the Time to answer :)

Comment: So, was it helpful? If you're satisfied with the answer, you should upvote it (a.k.a finish the case)

Comment: Hy Honza .....Sry for the late answer...No not realy I tried it with array_unshift($data, "uniqueid"); but this adds the uniqueid at the end of every row.....I solved my issue now by my old counter solution and after i add the counter i edit the file now with fopen...fread and a str_replace() and set the first line of the whole csv File to my needs....now my import in mysql runs perfectly...But upvote because you are the onlyone who anser ....Thank You again for helping or try to... ;)

Comment: The $data array is more complex than single dimensional array? It wasn't obvious from the piece of code you posted. I'm sure there is a more convenient way how to solve your case. Please describe more precisely $data array structure and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I Updatet my Post so you can see the code iam using...This adds a new column containing the counter values to my csv...line by line...so the lines are countet and i have a primary key to work with the file and mysql...all what i need there is a headline/firstline/header named uniqueid for the new column....but my problem is solved by another way now so its not realy needed anymore

Comment: So, the minor change is enough for your code to work fine - try it if you want...